# Row and Column search to map values to another df with python

Tags: loops, replace, mapping

I need to be able to find the values from one df in another by looking at each value per column per row.

Basically I have this df which is my main_df (note this is a mock up of the data in reality I have hundreds of columns and thousands of rows):

| user_id | fav_fruit | fav_veg | basket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | potato | apple |
| 2 | pear | potato | fruit |
| 3 | banana | carrot | fruit |
| 4 | apple | broccoli | carrot |

And I have another df whihch is my auxiliary_df:

| category | answer | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fav_fruit | apple | 0.5 |
| fav_fruit | pear | 0.5 |
| fav_fruit | banana | 0.8 |
| fav_veg | potato | 0.7 |
| fav_veg | carrot | 1 |
| fav_veg | broccoli | 1 |
| basket | apple | 3 |
| basket | fruit | 5 |
| basket | carrot | 3 |

I need to sear for each user id (row loop) find the column name in the auxiliary_df - category column, and within the answers in that category map what i have in my main_df as value with the auxiliary_df to get the value of that table so at the end I get the following:

| user_id | fav_fruit | fav_veg | basket |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 3 |
| 2 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 5 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 0.5 | 1 | 3 |

So at this point I repalced all the values from my main_df with the numerical values from the auxiliary_df. I cannot ma just by answer since many answers are repeated across categories so unsure how t map it properly. I dont know how to do this, I tried to do a dictionary to map but couldnt make it work to get the correct dection of category with answer and value. Also, I cannot hardcode anything since is hundreds of columns and values that change regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.pivot()` the `auxiliary_df` and `.map()`:

```py
tmp = auxiliary_df.pivot(index='answer', columns='category', values='value')

main_df = main_df.set_index('user_id')
for c in main_df:
    main_df[c] = main_df[c].map(tmp[c])
print(main_df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   user_id  fav_fruit  fav_veg  basket
0        1        0.5      0.7     3.0
1        2        0.5      0.7     5.0
2        3        0.8      1.0     5.0
3        4        0.5      1.0     3.0
```